# Как поставить номера телефонов справа от картинки?

Tags: html, css

[image: Как надо]

[image: Как получилось]

```
     <div class="top-info">
            <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                <div class="phone-left">
                <b>(048) 795-85-95
                (093) 795-85-95</b></div>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
```

Нужно чтобы моя картинка телефона встала также само, как на первой картинке + чтобы номера телефонов стояли справа от телефона как представлено на картинке.
Css стили я пытался поставить, но не знаю что именно для этого нужно, новичок, извините :(

Answer (score 3):

Примерно как-то так:

```css
.top-info {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  background-color: #34303f;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #42a1d8;
}

.contact-info {
  text-align: right;
}

.contact-info_item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid #494553;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: left;
}

.contact-info_item:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.contact-info_item:firsl-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.contact-info_item:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.contact-info_item .fa,
.contact-info_content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.contact-info_item .fa {
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact-info_content {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-info">
  <div class="contact-info">
    <div class="contact-info_item">
      <i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="contact-info_content">
        (048) 795-85-95<br>
        (093) 795-85-95
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-info_item">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="contact-info_content">
        Пн. - Пт.:10:00 - 19:00&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Суб:10:00 - 17:00
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько методик, первая, дай всем блокам float:left; потом просто роняй, вторая, сделай блоки display: inline-block; и траться, адаптивные сетки, и flex-box.
Твою проблему, решают все методики.